# Is adding Timer to main RunLoop the right solution?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a Timer that I want to continuously repeat at a given interval, however the only way I can seem to get the Timer to persist is by adding it to RunLoop.main like below:

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    blockToFire()
}
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```

I understand that using .commonModes should prevent the timer from missing its cue when a user interacts with the UI, but will the timer cause problems being added to the main run loop?  Will there be UI slow downs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted is fine. A runloop is associated with a particular thread. Timers are usually run on the main thread/main runloop. As such, they will cause "hiccups" in the main thread if their code takes too long to execute. Don't invoke blocks/selectors who's code takes a long time to run from the main thread/attach them to the main run loop, or you will cause a UI slowdown.

You can also create and run a timer on a background thread. I generally use one of the `scheduledTimer()` methods, which creates a timer and adds it to the "current run loop" (which means the run loop for the current thread.)

If you want to run a timer on a different thread, you can call one of the `scheduledTimer()` methods from your background thread. However beware that you should not make UIKit calls from a background thread.

### Edit:

I've seen conflicting info on whether background threads/queues get a run loop. [This (rather old) article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW24) says that they do not.

This [Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop) on the other hand says that the system creates run loops as needed for Thread objects.